# Spring Security with WebFlux: How to migrate "requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.to("status", "info"))"?

Tags: spring-security, spring-webflux

Using Spring Boot, SpringMVC and Spring Security I can configure the security part of my Spring Boot app as follows: `...requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.to("status", "info"))....`.

Now I'm migrating from SpringMVC to Spring WebFlux. I see that I've to use `pathMatchers()` instead of `requestMatchers`. However, `EndpointRequest` is depending on `HttpServletRequest` (and thus on Spring MVC). Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Indeed, you might have a point; could you open an issue on https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues ? Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/11022